Gitlab CI: did not find expected comment or line break error with |
I have a CI stage:
deploy_block:
  tags:
    - block_autotest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR" | .\dorelease.bat
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - BlockSetup.zip
    expire_in: 1 day

But this CI config fails at initialisation with the next error:
`.gitlab-ci.yml`: (): did not find expected comment or line break while scanning a block scalar at line 112 column 29

Line 112 refers to - "$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR" | .\dorelease.bat, column 29 refers to "| ". I have found that other guys experience the same problem with using | symbol in script command, but I couldnt find any proper solutions...
More details: dorelease.bat script must take path to folder as stdin, thats why I need |.
